# Being sued for an e-book

Tags: publishing

Is there any chance of being sued for any information I publish in an e-book, and is there a suitable disclaimer to protect me?

At present I do not imagine that there is much of a risk, but I am not sure about the future.

In the area of patents, there seem to be cases of litigation undertaken to harass or otherwise undermine the patent holders rights.

Comment: The question needs to be more specific; are you worried about specific content? Can you describe this content? Or are you worried about being harassed by patent trolls?

Comment: You are worried about being sued, but not enough to get legal advice **in the country where you live**. Instead you ask a question on an online Q&A site, without telling us where you live. So this has close to 200 possible correct answers (i.e. one per country), that by far too broad a question for this site.

Comment: Great answers, thanks.  This certainly gives me useful information for further action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard about patent trolls going after ebook publishers, but if you use images in an unauthorized way, that can expose you to lawsuits.

You have probably seen the verbiage: "This is a work of fiction. Names, characters, places and plot are products of the author's imagination. Any resemblance to persons living or dead is coincidental." It's probably good to include language like that.

Acknowledging trademarks is also sensible.

Most of these legal hassles are best covered by contracts. A publisher can require the author to assume responsibility for copyright infringements, but practically speaking, the publisher has the most to lose.

The question needs to be more specific; are you worried about specific content? Can you describe this content? Or are you worried about being harassed by patent trolls?

If for example you published in ebook form  some source code from software like  MS Office (or something similar) and the software company became aware of it, most certainly you would be sued (but for good reason).

Answer (score 1):

There is a risk. It could be for damages resulting from content errors, copyright infringement (text or illustrations), slander or libel.

The risk is heightened if you self publish (ie. on Amazon, Apple etc.) since self-publishers can make mistakes that a publishing company might have otherwise corrected.

If you have significant ebook sales you should incorporate your business to limit liability and protect personal assets. In the US there are many companies that create low cost LLC's (Limited Liability Corporation). You can use the LLC for other business endeavors you might have. Mine costs me about $150 US per year to keep running.

Even with an LLC, you can be sued. So you should also consider *General Liability Insurance* for small business. You can get quotes online quickly.